# Using RegEx to separate camelCase - how do i include special characters?

Tags: javascript, regex

This is the syntax I am using:

```
.split(' ')
.join('+')
.replace(/([A-Z])/g, ' $1')
.replace(/^./, function(str) {
    return str.toUpperCase();
})
.replace(/\++/g, '')
.replace(/asdf/g, ';')
.replace(';', '')
.replace(' ', '')
.split(';');
```

This code helps me to turn 'camelCase' into 'Camel Case'. I also try to do a variety of other things, like replacing excess spaces with just one space through the '+'s. I also replace 'asdf' with ; and then cut of the first ; and the first space.

Problem: At the same time though, it breaks my german special characters, namely ÄÖÜ. turning them into question marks in my output.

```
I BELIEVE IT GENERATES OUTPUT LIKE THIS:

input: ... Oberbayern:Kreis EichstättAsdf ...
output: ... Oberbayern: Kreis Eichst�tt; Asdf ...
```

Please help me.

Comment: Please add the input string

Comment: Alright. I added my whole regex with example input/output.

Comment: That input isn't camelCase.

Comment: It's not camelCase as you said.

Comment: This kinda begs the question of why the `\w` class doesn't match unicode letters in JavaScript...

Comment: That's too much code for converting `camelCase` to `Camel Case`. Can you explain what all those `replace` are doing. Actual input and expected output.

Comment: That code has a lot of things unrelated to doing the conversion, and you have a replacea t the end removing spaces -- which is kind of a problem when you're adding them earlier on. That code is clearly **not** producing the output you've described.

Comment: I am trying to do a number of other things. Please do not downvote if this is not the most efficient way. I am by no means an expert at this. I am getting horrible strings from a old backend. I then try to get rid of a number of double/triple-spaces, thus converting them into '+' and then replacing excess '+' with nothing again. The string 'asdf' is my break point which is why i convert it to ';'.

Comment: We can't help you correctly if you don't tell us what you need to do. Clearly, you need to do more than just the camelCase change. You've quoted code and said it gives you the output you've shown, but it demonstrably doesn't. The question is unclear and has been since the beginning, so don't be surprised if people downvote it. Instead, take the time to be clear and thorough (ideally *before* posting).

Comment: Alright. I ll try. Let me do another edit to my question...

Comment: what do you mean by cutting off the first `;` and the first space? And instead of all this mess you can normalize the whitespace with `.replace(/\s+/g, " ")`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like this:

**Logic**

- Check for any small character followed by caps character.
- Replace it by adding space to it.
- Now make 1st character uppercase

**Note:** as pointed out by [T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder), its better to use [string.toLocaleUpperCase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLocaleUpperCase), if available.

```js
function seperateCamelCaseWords(a) {
  var regex = /([a-z])(?=[A-Z])/g;

  a = a.replace(regex, "$1 ");
  a = upper(a.charAt(0)) + a.substring(1)
  console.log(a)
  return a;
}

function upper(str){
  return str.toLocaleUpperCase ? str.toLocaleUpperCase() : str.toUpperCase();
}

var a = "thisIsTestString";
var b = "kreisEichstätt"

seperateCamelCaseWords(a);
seperateCamelCaseWords(b);
```

You can also use following logic to match any character except space followed by a Capital character.

```js
function seperateCamelCaseWords(a) {
  var regex = /([^ ])(?=[A-Z])/g;
  a = a.replace(regex, "$1 ");
  a = upper(a.charAt(0)) + a.substring(1)
  console.log(a)
  return a;
}

function upper(str){
  return str.toLocaleUpperCase ? str.toLocaleUpperCase() : str.toUpperCase();
}

seperateCamelCaseWords("thisIsATestString");
seperateCamelCaseWords("kreisEichstätt");
seperateCamelCaseWords("kreisäEichstätt")
```

Comment: @Tushar Updated my snippet with OP's string. If there is any mistake please point it out. :-)

Comment: Recommend adding a note about [ECMA-402](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-402/3.0/index.html) and using `toLocaleUpperCase` if it's available. Particularly important with German, I believe.